# Load all results of JSON API to source variable on page-load in jQuery autocomplete

Tags: jquery, jquery-autocomplete

I have an autocomplete script using jQuery that would query my site's autocomplete API under `http://example.com/autocomplete?term=[blah]`.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function()
    {
        $.ui.autocomplete.prototype._renderItem = function( ul, item){
            var term = this.term.split(' ').join('|');
            var re = new RegExp("(" + term + ")", "gi") ;
            var t = item.label.replace(re,"<b>$1</b>");
            return $( "<li></li>" )
                    .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
                    .append( "<a>" + t + "</a>" )
                    .appendTo( ul );
        };
        $( "#q" ).autocomplete({
            source: '{{ URL('autocomplete') }}',
            minLength: 3,
            delay: 0,
            select: function(event, ui) {
                $('#q').val(ui.item.value);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

The query is quite slow - looking at the profiler the range is from 100 ms to 700 ms, which is way too slow. The reason behind this is, it queries my API every time I type.

I am thinking on page-load I simply want to download all results (by sending an empty value to the `term=`, which returns all results in the JSON format) to an array, and have the `source` all loaded to the client on page-load.

However.. I am very new to front-end programming in general, and I have no idea how to begin.

Comment: It depends on how many records you have.  You are making a trade-off between extra initial download time (and bandwidth) and smaller individual queries.  Also have you looked at ways to optimize the query on the backend?

Comment: Yeah. I notice there is a trade-off for speed. But I think the trade off is fine, and I'll tweak it depending on the feedback/performance.

Answer (score 0):

The following code makes an AJAX request to get my autocomplete list from my API. It returns all 1600 rows of data. The load time for the page may be a little slow.. but the autocomplete is quick.

```
    // once page loads, make AJAX request to get your autocomplete list and apply to HTML
    $.ajax({ url: '{{ URL('autocomplete') }}',
        type: "GET",
        contentType: "application/json",
        success: function(tags) {
            $( "#q" ).autocomplete({
                source: tags,
                minLength: 3,
                delay: 0,
                select: function(event, ui) {
                    $('#q').val(ui.item.value);
                }
            });
        }
    });
```